# Warning During upgrading a Tensorflow 1 code to Tensorflow 2 code

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to convert an existing TF1 code to TF2 code on google colab. I get 14 of this warning message after I run the command:  !tf_upgrade_v2 --infile medgan.py --outfile medgan_upgraded.py

WARNING: tf.get_variable requires manual check. tf.get_variable returns ResourceVariables by default in 2.0, which have well-defined semantics and are stricter about shapes. You can disable this behavior by passing use_resource=False, or by calling tf.compat.v1.disable_resource_variables().

I am new to tensorflow and not sure what this command mean. What should be my next step before saving the upgraded .py file? Should I worry about these warnings? What is TF telling me to do by this warning? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrating code from `Tensorflow 1.x` to `Tensorflow 2.x` using Automated script will just do an initial pass. But in the process, you need to note that there are many things which won't fall under `Tensorflow 2.x` implementations such as `placeholders`, `sessions`, `collections`,t`f.contrib`, and other 1.x functionalities including changes in the behavior of `variables`.

First, let me tell you the difference between `tf.get_variable` and `tf.Variable`.

`tf.get_variable` gets an existing variable with specifies parameters from the graph, and if it doesn't exist it creates a new one, whereas `tf.Variable` will always create a new variable, even if the same name is passed, Tensorflow will assign the new name with the suffix *variable_name*_1.

In `Tensorflow 2.x` using `tf.Variable` creates a Resource variable as default with eager execution is enabled by default.

You don't have to worry about this warning unless you are facing behavior in your variables usage.
If you want to disable the resource variable  `tf.compat.v1.disable_resource_variables()` is depreciated instead you can use `use_resource= False` in `tf.get_variable()` which will be forced to true when eager excecution is enabled by default in `Tensorflow 2.x`.

You can see all the other changes and observations to be made during migrating your code from [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) documentation from Tensorflow.